# java random number generator

Tags: java

I don not understand  what roll < 1000 does. i mean i do not see why its being used when the rand function generates the random numbers.

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int freq[] = new int[7];
        for (int roll = 1; roll < 1000; roll++) { // is there a reason for roll<1000
            ++freq[1 + rand.nextInt(6)];
        }
        System.out.println("Face \tFrequency");
        for (int face = 1; face < freq.length; face++) {
            System.out.println(face + "\t" + freq[face]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `roll` is just the loop counter. The loop iterates 999 times. Nothing strange about it.

Comment: It is generating a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram). You have a six sided die (`int freq [] = new int [7];`) and you are rolling it 999 times (`int roll =1; roll<1000`) and keeping track of the number of times you land on each side.

Comment: I hope you are not an employee in the company where you saw that code. Otherwise, that company is going bankrupt :)

Comment: @jbabey Right! Well seen, it seems like a dice! I was wondering why 7 ints were allocated but only 6 were used and printed... It it probably to match the number on the dice, which start are 1 and not 0. You should put that as an answer, it is the exact explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int roll =1; roll<1000;roll++){ // is there  a reason  for roll<1000
    ++freq[1+rand.nextInt(6)];
}
```

What does here is add +1 to a random position on the freq array for 999 times.

The "real" randome here is
    rand.nextInt(6) 
which generates a number between 0 and 6.

Here:

```
for( int face=1;face<freq.length;face++){
    System.out.println(face + "\t"+freq[face]);
}
```

Prints the 6 numbers on the freq array

Clean and easy code:

```
`public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Creates an instance of Random and allocates 
        //the faces of the dices on memory
        Random rand = new Random();
        int freq[] = new int[6];

        //Rolls the dice 1000 times to make a histogram
        for (int roll = 0; roll < 1000; roll++) {
            ++freq[rand.nextInt(6)];
        }

        //Prints the frequency that any face is shown
        System.out.println("Face \tFrequency");
        for (int face = 0; face < freq.length; face++) {
            System.out.println(face + "\t" + freq[face]);
        }
    }
}`
```

Now it has 6 int allocated on memory as the dice faces, rolls 1000 times and is simple to understand as it should be

Comment: Technially it prints the last 6 numbers! I am not sure why 7 int are allocated but only 6 are used...

Comment: Yup, you're right, I'm editing it right now.

Comment: Edited! Sorry for the miss. Also, this code has to be posted on codecrap.com ...

Answer (score 0):

Because they only want to generate up to 999 random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The roll in this case is used as a counter in the for loop to break the loop once the limit has been reached. In this example the limit is `1000`. Since roll is initialized to 1, it will generate `999` numbers.